# Check to see if Object exist in list of Objects

Tags: c#, .net, list, equality

What i need is what Code i should replace this: `<-- code (exist) -->` with.

I have a class that creates cells in a table. I am storing these cells in an list of cells.

```
List<Cell> locations = new List<Cell>();
```

I am tring to find out if a cell exist in that list. I am doing the following:

```
cell_in_array(new Cell(x, y));

public bool cell_in_array(Cell cell)
{
    if(<-- code (exist) -->){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false
    }           
}
```

Cell Class

```
public class Cell
{
    int x_pos; // column
    int y_pos;// row
    public Cell(int col, int row)
    {
        x_pos = col;
        y_pos = row;
    }

    public int getRow()
    {
        return y_pos;
    }
    public int getColumn()
    {
        return x_pos;
    }
    public int[] position()
    {
        int[] cell_loc = { x_pos, y_pos };
        return cell_loc;
    }
}
```

Comment: `bool inArray = locations.Any(c => c.getColumn() == cell.getColumn() && c.getRow() == cell.getRow());`

Comment: just iterate through list and check its position.

Comment: I suggest to remove that java style calls _getRow_ and _getColumn_ and replace them with more C# properties

Comment: @Steve will do that. I am Learning Java and C# at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your life easy by using an impelmentation of `IEqualityComparer<Cell>`.
I use this solution because maybe you will need that seme logic somewhere.

```
public class CellComparer : IEqualityComparer<Cell>
{
    public bool Equals(Cell x, Cell y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) return true;

        if (x == null || y == null) return false;

        if (x.Column == y.Column && x.Row == y.Row) return true;

        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Cell cell)
    {
        int hCode = cell.Column ^ cell.Row;
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

To use it it just simple and if you check the list content you will see that it contains two elements because the first and the last added cells are equally the same.

```
var list = new HashSet<Cell>(new CellComparer());
list.Add(new Cell(0, 1));
list.Add(new Cell(1, 2));
list.Add(new Cell(0, 1));
```

Say thanks to `HashSet` who will use your `CellComparer` to avoid `Cell` duplication.

So use auto-property instead of method to return a value of a field. Your cell class must looks like this:

```
public class Cell
{
    public Cell(int col, int row)
    {
        Column = col;
        Row = row;
    }

    public int Row { get; private set; }

    public int Column { get; private set; }

    public int[] Position
    {
        get { return new[] { Column, Row }; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `IEquatable` interface to the Cell class:

```
public class Cell : IEquatable<Cell>
```

which requires a `bool` method `Equals` in the class:

```
public bool Equals(Cell otherCell)
```

in which you provide a code to tell, when `this` Cell is equal to the `otherCell` (e.g., `this.getRow() == otherCell.getRow()` etc.).

If `Cell` is `IEquatable`, it allows you to use `Contains` method on lists of Cells. So in your main code, instead of `<-- code (exist) -->` you can use `locations.Contains(cell)`.

And you should really think about rewriting your `Cell` class using Properties.

Comment: I like this solution. it will help out later. as well

Answer (score 1):

you can use linq to do that

```
public bool cell_in_array(Cell cell)
{
    return locations.Any(c => c.getColumn() == cell.getColumn() && 
                              c.getRow() == cell.getRow())         
}
```

`Any` will determine if any element matches the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.90).aspx) to determine whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition:

```
locations.Any(c => c.getColumn() == cell.getColumn() && c.getRow() == cell.getRow())
```